# Some help to factorize code base on permission

Tags: php, symfony, bit-manipulation

Morning,

with this code (symfony mask builder)

```
     MASK_VIEW         = 1;          // 1 << 0
     MASK_CREATE       = 2;          // 1 << 1
     MASK_EDIT         = 4;          // 1 << 2
     MASK_DELETE       = 8;          // 1 << 3
     MASK_UNDELETE     = 16;         // 1 << 4
     MASK_OPERATOR     = 32;         // 1 << 5
     MASK_MASTER       = 64;         // 1 << 6
     MASK_OWNER        = 128;
```

for a given resource,i store permission (int) by additionning theses permissions,with a basic example, i add: view, create, edit, will give 7.

So my question is how to "split" this 7 to retrieve thoses granted permissions.

i have a working code, with "if" and "else", but that's just ugly, so any "beautiful mind" would help on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not something you will do it with split but with bitwise operartor. Just chek this out:

- [Permissions Using Bitwise](http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/create-permissions-using-bitwise-operators-in-php/).

If the values are coming from database you also can refer to:

- [Implementation of User permission with PHP & Mysql Bitwise
  operators](http://sforsuresh.in/implemention-of-user-permission-with-php-mysql-bitwise-operators/).